# How to dynamically calculate the YTD for current year without using a table calculation in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

How do I dynamically calculate the Year To Date (YTD) for the current year without using a table calculation in Tableau?

I have used the below formulas to calculate YoY for the current year:

```
if datediff('year',[Date],TODAY())=0 then [Sales]  END
```

For the previous year:

```
if datediff('year',[Date],TODAY())=1 then [Sales]  END
```

YoY:

```
sum(current year)/sum(previous year)-1
```

Comment: The question is for YTD not YoY. That was a mistake.My bad

Answer (score 0):

create a calculated field:

```
[date] >= MAKEDATE(Year(today()),1,1) and
[date]<= today()
```

Drag this to filter and select `True`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're trying to achieve. If you want to filter dates to show only values in the current year without a table calculation, then you could create a calculated field like below and filter on the result:

```
if Year([Date]) =  YEAR(TODAY()) then "YTD" else "Not" END
```